# Can you use pmrep createConnection command with parameter in Password

Tags: informatica

Is there a way to create a connection in Informatica **from the pmrep command line tool** with the "Use Parameter in Password" option? This is simple from the GUI I need to automate the process via a script.

**Here is the command I am running:**

```
pmrep createconnection -s Oracle -n DummyConn -u $ParamTEST_DB_USERNAME -p $ParamTEST_DB_PASSWORD -c TEST123 -l US-ASCII
```

I have tried the following without luck:

1. -p option which simply treats the password as a normal
2. -P option which complains there is no environment variable by that name
3. -k with "Use Parameter In Password"=true

Answer (score 0):

-P is the correct way to go for you.

But before running the command you need to run these 2 commands :

**export $ParamTEST_DB_USERNAME= << Your Username >>** 
**export $ParamTEST_DB_PASSWORD= << Password encrypted with pmpasswd >>**

The rest of your command seems fine

Comment: Thanks for your response, the goal is to supply the password from a parameter file. So when you look at the connection object in the informatica GUI you would see in plain text in the password field "$ParamTEST_DB_PASSWORD" and the "Use Parameter in Password" would be checked. I tried the above solution but it seems it sets a standard Password from the environment variable

Comment: In that case, you can leave the GUI part as it is, keeping the "Use Parameter in Password" checked. But in the parameter file you pass to the workflow define the parameters as $ParamTEST_DB_USERNAME=<your ussername> and $ParamTEST_DB_PASSWORD=<encrypted passord>.  Please note for Oracle connection you will need to encrypt it with "pmpasswd <your password> -e CRYPT_DATA

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. My question is is it possible to do this from pmcmd (The Informatica command line tool), I am able to do it from the GUI already. I am working on automating the process of creating the connection object. I can currently create a connection object from the command line, the thing I am still stuck on is setting the "Use Parameter in Password" setting from the command line. Thanks for your time.